# Make a 10x10 board using java swing

Tags: java, swing, grid, jbutton

I'm trying to make a `10x10 board` with java swing. But i don't know why one of the box is out of the place. The other `99 grid` is on place as i set in `setBounds()`, but the last grid is in `0,0 position`. 
i'm using `jButton` as a `grid`. Any hints of what i am doing wrong? 
the code i write so far :

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JButton[][] grid;
int y = 10;
int x = 10;
public Board() {
    initComponents();
    jButton = new JButton[x][y];
    setGrid();
}
private javax.swing.JButton[][] jButton;
public void setGrid(){
    int size = 75;
    int o = size * x;
    int p = size * y;

    int k = 0;
    int l = 0;
    int z = 9;
    for(int i=p;i>0;i-=size){
        for(int j=0;j<o;j+=size){
            jButton[k][l] = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton[k][l].setBounds(j, i, size, size);
            jButton[k][l].setBackground(Color.yellow);
            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
            this.setLayout(layout);

            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton[k][l])
                    )

            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton[k][l])
                    ));
            if(k==9){
                k=0;
            }
            else{
                k++;
            }
        }l++;
     }   
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Board");
    frame.setContentPane(new Board());
    Dimension dmsn = new Dimension();
    dmsn.height = 1080;
    dmsn.width = 1920;
    Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
    frame.setMinimumSize(dmsn);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i=p;i>0;i-=size){
        for(int j=0;j<o;j+=size){
            jButton[k][l] = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton[k][l].setBounds(j, i, size, size);
            jButton[k][l].setBackground(Color.yellow);
            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
            this.setLayout(layout);
```

1. You are creating a new layout each time the loop gets executed. Put the `setLayout` code before the loop.
2. Don't set bounds while working layout other than the `NULL` layout
3. Use [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) when you intend to make your `Container` to be grid.
4. Don't use `GroupLayout` while hand coding: working with it is not impossible but, tedious.

Comment: this can be misspelled, but +1 for rest